# Powershell Script error... script is missing terminator

Tags: powershell

```
    $ServicePath = Split-Path(Get-WmiObject win32_service -ComputerName $ServerName -Filter "name like '$ServiceName**'"|selectPathName)**
```

The error that is coming is script is missing terminator: 
error is being shown in the last cmdlet highlighed between asterisk.
note- Asterisk is to specify teh error portion it is not actually included in the code
Pls tell how to remove this error.

Comment: you are missing a space here `select PathName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
split-path (Get-WmiObject win32_service  -ComputerName $ServerName -Filter "name like '$ServiceName'" |select -expand PathName)
```